# What is the difference between write_actions(pop_vlan) and actions=pop_vlan?

Tags: sdn, openflow

What is the difference between these two openflow instructions:

```
 cookie=0x13baf, duration=46.823s, table=4, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=35,dl_vlan=772 actions=pop_vlan,goto_table:6
```

And the following:

```
 cookie=0x13baf, duration=1.891s, table=4, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=35,dl_vlan=772 actions=write_actions(pop_vlan),goto_table:6
```

Also is strip_vlan supported in openflow 1.3 ?  Thanks. Ranga

Answer (score 0):

Answer was found in the OpenFlow Switch Specification
Version 1.3.1.:

Optional  Instruction:
Apply-Actions  Applies  the  specific  action(s)  immediately,
without any change to the Action Set.  This instruction may be used to modify the packet between two tables or to execute multiple actions of the same type.  The actions are specified as an action
list (see 5.11).

Write-actions Merges the specified action(s) into the current
action set (see 5.10).  If an action of the given type exists in the current set, overwrite it, otherwise add it